# Touchpad not freezing and moving slow

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I just changed my OS from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 and I was having a great time but the touchpad started to freeze or moving really REALLY slow. What can I do?

PS: My notebook is an Acer Aspire E5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Acer. Go to your BIOS page (mine was pressing f2 on startup) go to main and look for touchpad change it from advanced to basic and that should solve your problems.